# How to install a managed package for a specific role?

Tags: managed-package, permissions

Is there a way to install a managed package for a specific role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by specific **role** do you mean specific profile? then yes.

Otherwise no.

You only can install for 
1) Admins
2) All Users
3) Specific Profiles
[image]
The only workaround you could do is to customize by #3 - Specific profiles
[image]